# Firebase database query with multiple condition

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, data-structures, nosql

i am straggling for two days trying to find a proper solution to query Firebase database with multiple condition, and filter to be done on the server side not the client side as i have a huge amount of records, the below is my schema, trying to query where **journeyId**=$journeyId and **date** BETWEEN $date1 AND $date2;

```
{
  "-MdqIEA4CwKH29PMG0Op" : {
    "comment" : "",
    "date" : 1625482389127,
    "device" : "iPhone 11",
    "journeyId" : "eTopup_mobile_iOS",
    "os" : "iOS 14.6",
    "rating" : 4
  },
  "-MeAagXopUMzptv-koPA" : {
    "comment" : "",
    "date" : 1625839812343,
    "device" : "iPhone 7 Plus",
    "journeyId" : "eTopup_mobile_ANDROID",
    "os" : "iOS 14.6",
    "rating" : 4
  },
  "-MeJX9PBaP3xGx255Pv9" : {
    "comment" : "",
    "date" : 1625989619199,
    "device" : "iPhone XR",
    "journeyId" : "eTopup_WEB",
    "os" : "iOS 14.6",
    "rating" : 5
  }
}
```